# Remove xaml data template duplication

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add tooltips to TWO expander panels in my UI. Both need a button at the end with tooltip on it. So , What I have done is I have added two dynamic resources in my Windows.Resources as follows.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PropertiesExpanderHeader">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="760">
                <Label Content="Reservoir properties" Width="120"></Label>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Height="24" IsEnabled ="{Binding IsSelected}" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="560,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Image Source="../Resource/quickHelp.png" Width ="18" Height ="18"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel Width="360" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFF9F4F4" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"   MaxWidth="360">
                                            <Run FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#FF151514" Text="Input properties that can be used to find similar projects in the database

"></Run>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailsExpanderHeader">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="760">
                <Label Content="Reservoir properties" Width="120"></Label>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Height="24" IsEnabled ="{Binding IsSelected}" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="560,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Image Source="../Resource/quickHelp.png" Width ="18" Height ="18"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button.ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel Width="360" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FFF9F4F4" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"   MaxWidth="360">
                                            <Run FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="#FF151514" Text="1) Input project details  &#x0a;
2) Confidential project is only visible to the project team and super users, and hidden from common browsers."
></Run>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
```

Now I am using this by calling the data template on the Header field of expander.

```
    <Expander Name="PropertiesExpander" IsExpanded="True" Header="Reservoir properties" HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource PropertiesExpanderHeader}"  >

    <Expander Name="DetailsExpander" IsExpanded="True" Header="Details" HeaderTemplate="{DynamicResource DetailsExpanderHeader}"  >
```

If you see the two Data templates , u can see its exactly same except for the Text fields. I know a golden rule of programming is avoid duplication. Any pointers on how I can keep different text without repeating code ? Preferrably keep the same dynamic resource implementation?

Comment: Make a new UserControl

Comment: I think, if you separate data from its representation you will be happy.

Comment: There are at least a few different ways to address the question, some preferable than others, but the choice of which depends at least somewhat on what the program looks like now. Ideally, you can use a view model to represent your expanders, and use a single data template that binds the tooltip text to a property in the model. But without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question, it's hard to know exactly what's best for your case.

Comment: Note that the code example you've provided so far contains _more_ XAML than is likely required to illustrate the question, and at the same time is missing the XAML and code-behind that would allow someone to fully understand your scenario.